# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to print three variables, but I am getting a AttributeError

```
"1 -3 JANE STREET "
"217- 219 EASTERN PARKWAY "
"219 -223 78TH STREET "
"28-31 34TH ST "
```

Sample data for row['address'] (above)

```
import csv
import re
with open('/Users/d/Desktop/bldg_zip_codes.csv', 'r+') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        if row['address'] != None:
          addy1 = re.search(r'\d\d-\d\d', row['address'])
          addy2 = re.search(r'-\s\d\d', row['address'])
          addy3 = re.search(r'\d\s-\d', row['address'])
          print(addy1.group(), addy2.group(), addy3.group())

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "excludenumsonst.py", line 46, in <module>
 print(addy1.group(), addy2.group(), addy3.group())
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Why am I getting this error if I have already excluded NoneType on line 6?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you think `row['address']` is the None?

Comment: if row['address'] != None:

Comment: That's not going to do anything about your None problem. Checking whether `row['address']` is None won't help you when the None is some other variable.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'* appears when your regex has not matched anything inside the provided input string, because the match object is None, not initialized, the `.group()` is None.

The `\d\d-\d\d` pattern will only match `28-31` in `28-31 34TH ST`, `-\s\d\d` will only match `- 21` in `217- 219 EASTERN PARKWAY`, and `\d\s-\d` will match `1 -3` and `9 -2` in `1 -3 JANE STREET` and `219 -223 78TH STREET`.

To match the initial digits with a hyphen, you can use

```
^\d+\s*-\s*\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qO9uF0/1)

In code, you can use `re.match` to match in the beginning of a string rather than use `^` with `re.search`:

```
if row['address']:                                    # Check if address is present
    add = re.match(r'\d+\s*-\s*\d+', row['address'])  # Run the regex
    if add:                                           # Regex matched?
        print(add.group())                            # Print the match value
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't exclude `None` simply because it is generated from `re.search`. Your regular expressions doesn't match what you need to extract. The first regexp matches a succession of 2 digits followed by a hyphen then followed by another 2 digits, for example `"28-31"`. The second regexp matches a hyphen followed by space then followed by 2 digits, for example : `"- 21"`. The last one matches a digit followed a space then followed by a hyphen then another digit, for example : `"1 -3"`.

You have to check those regular expressions to make them match what you need.